# Incorrect rectangle location in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm making a plot with bars and I'm trying to find their absolute location (in pixels) on the plot for further processing later.  It seems to me that this should be able to be figured out from matplotlib's transformation information on the axes instance.  Specifically, I'm using [`ax.transData`](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html) to go from data coordinates (where I know the box positions) to display coordinates.  Here is some code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = range(10)
y = range(1, 11)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
bars = ax.bar(x, y, width=.5, label="foo")
ax.monkey_rectangles = bars
ax.legend()

def get_useful_info(fig):
    for ax in fig.get_axes():
        for rect in ax.monkey_rectangles:
            corners = rect.get_bbox().corners()[::3]
            pos = ax.transData.transform(corners)
            left = pos[0,0]
            width = pos[1,0] - pos[0,0]
            bottom = pos[0,1]
            height = pos[1,1] - pos[0,1]
            yield left, width, bottom, height

fig.savefig('foo.png')
for l, w, b, h in get_useful_info(fig):
    print l, w, b, h
```

This prints the following:

```
80.0 24.8 48.0 38.4
129.6 24.8 48.0 76.8
179.2 24.8 48.0 115.2
228.8 24.8 48.0 153.6
278.4 24.8 48.0 192.0
328.0 24.8 48.0 230.4
377.6 24.8 48.0 268.8
427.2 24.8 48.0 307.2
476.8 24.8 48.0 345.6
526.4 24.8 48.0 384.0
```

So, matplotlib thinks my boxes are 24.8 units (pixels I assume) wide.  That's fine except when I actually go to measure the box width, I get something more like 32 pixels wide.  What is the discrepancy here?

Comment: You might be better off working in figure fraction units, and then feeding that number + the final saved figure size in pixels into your later processing.

Comment: @tcaswell -- do you mean figure units -- e.g. the result of `fig.transData`?

Comment: err... `fig.transFigure` I suppose ...

Comment: yeah, but you probably have to get there via data -> window -> inverse_figure.

Comment: I assume you have seen this http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html page

Comment: This PR _may_ fix some of the issues with this: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/3081

Answer (score 3):

As usual, the revelation happens when posting the question ... The problem here is that the units **are not pixels**, they're dots.  When the figure is initialized, it is set up with a default dots per inch (`fig.set_dpi()` and `fig.get_dpi()` allow you to change/inquire the current figure's resolution).  Of course, things can't be that easy -- When you save the figure, the dpi changes based on your rc settings for the particular backend.  For me with the  default backend and png output, this goes to 100 dpi.  One thing which is invariant here, however is the figure size `fig.get_size_inches()`.  So, if I scale my results, things seem to turn our a little more consistently ...

```
def get_useful_info(fig):
    dpi = fig.get_dpi()
    pngdpi = 100
    scale_x = pngdpi / dpi
    scale_y = pngdpi / dpi
    for ax in fig.get_axes():
        for rect in ax.monkey_rectangles:
            corners = rect.get_bbox().corners()[::3]
            pos = ax.transData.transform(corners)
            left = pos[0,0] * scale_x
            width = (pos[1,0] - pos[0,0]) * scale_x
            bottom = pos[0,1] * scale_y
            height = (pos[1,1] - pos[0,1]) * scale_y
            yield left, width, bottom, height
```

I have a sinking feeling that this isn't the full solution though -- After all, we're still working in dots.  I'm not completely sure how a dot translates to a pixel for png images ... My hope is that the display engine (in my particular case, a web browser) renders each dot in a single pixel and doesn't care about the image's reported size.  I suppose that only some experimentation will sort that one out ...

Answer (score 1):

As you are referring to web-browsers, I assume you are building image maps?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = range(10)
y = range(1, 11)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
bars = ax.bar(x, y, width=.5, label="foo")
ax.monkey_rectangles = bars
ax.legend()

def fig_fraction_info(fig):
    for ax in fig.get_axes():
        inv = fig.transFigure.inverted()
        # transformations are applied left to right
        my_trans = ax.transData + inv 
        for rect in ax.monkey_rectangles:
            corners = rect.get_bbox().corners()[::3]
            pos = my_trans.transform(corners)
            left = pos[0,0]
            width = pos[1,0] - pos[0,0]
            bottom = pos[0,1]
            height = pos[1,1] - pos[0,1]
            yield left, width, bottom, height
```

I think something like this is what you want.  If you feed this data and the png into the next level of code you can sort out exactly where everything is.

Issues like this are (I think) a consequence of way that matplotlib abstracts the backend from the front end.  Thinking about the size in pixels doesn't make a lot of sense for vector outputs.

Alternately:

```
dpi = 300
...
fig.set_dpi(dpi)
...
fig.savefig(..., dpi=dpi)
```

Comment: I am building image maps -- Before I read your post I was trying to do it via `div` and a bunch of css horror... Thanks for that comment.  however, building maps, I don't see how having the percentage is better than the absolute pixel value since `<area>` doesn't seem to accept percentages.

Comment: because what ever code you are using to generate the code can open the png and ask it how big it is and use that to convert % -> pixels

Comment: The image maps are being generated by matplotlib on GAE and are being served dynamically.  In other words, the image lives inline in an html document and never touches the disk unless a user decides to "save image as".  I suppose I could use PIL to inquire the image's size ... But it seems easier to just generate it to a known size and  go from there.

Comment: ah, hopefully explicitly controlling the dpi (see edit) will help.

Comment: Right, that's the option  I was gonna go with.  `fig.savefig(..., dpi=fig.get_dpi())`

Comment: also see http://www.dalkescientific.com/writings/diary/archive/2005/04/24/interactive_html.html  and http://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#matplotlib-in-a-web-application-server